# How to provide CassandraEntityInformation<T, ID> for a SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm doing some research bout `spring-data-cassandra-reactive` and it looks like I can't figure out or find the right documentation about this.

According to the documentation you can create an `interface` which is annotated with `@Repository` and then use annotations to create custom queries that will retrieve the data you want. The code would look something like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository
        extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserEntity, UUID>
{

    @Query("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE username = :user ALLOW FILTERING")
    Mono<UserEntity> findUserEntityByUsername(@Param("user") String user);

    /**
     * This is just to illustrate/simulate some custom/advanced logic that cannot be
     * done via @Query()
     */
    default Mono<UserEntity> saveWithBase64EncodedPassword(UserEntity entity)
    {
        String encodedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(entity.getPassword().getBytes());
        entity.updatePassword(encodedPassword);
        return this.save(entity);
    }

}


@Table(UserEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class UserEntity
{

    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "users";

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "uuid", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.UUID)
    @Column
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.VARCHAR)
    private String username;

    @Column
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.VARCHAR)
    private String password;

    public UserEntity()
    {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public UserEntity(String username, String password)
    {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UUID getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void updatePassword(String newPassword)
    {
        this.password = newPassword;
    }

}
```

Dependencies:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {

    // Embedded Cassandra Server - used for testing.
    implementation("com.github.nosan:embedded-cassandra-spring-boot-starter:4.1.0")

    // Spring Data Cassandra Dependencies
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine")
        exclude("com.vaadin.external.google:android-json")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    // /Spring Data Cassandra Dependencies
}
```

This, so far, works fine. However, I'm trying to figure out how to switch to implementing the interface in order to be able to use `@Autowire` (i.e. in this example code to autowire
`org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder`)

Surfing through the code in the `spring-data-cassandra` jar I noticed there's a class named `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository` which you can extend from. It already has most of the common things you would need implemented for you which is why it looks like the perfect candidate to `extend` from.

And here comes the problem - it requires `CassandraEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata`.
I cannot seem to find where this is taken from or how it's supposed to be auto-wired and I feel like I might be missing something or maybe a dependency.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository` is a great class as it gives you access to `ReactiveCassandraOperations` and as such to `CqlSession`. It is a great way to have fine grained operations. (LWT, Bacthes)

You are correct the different classes would be autowired. Here is a sample code:

```
@Repository
public class OwnerReactiveCassandraRepository extends SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository<OwnerEntitySpring, UUID> {

protected final CqlSession cqlSession;
protected final ReactiveCassandraOperations reactiveCassandraTemplate;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public OwnerReactiveCassandraRepository(CqlSession cqlSession, ReactiveCassandraOperations ops) {
    super(new MappingCassandraEntityInformation<OwnerEntitySpring, UUID>(
            (CassandraPersistentEntity<OwnerEntitySpring>) ops.getConverter().getMappingContext()
            .getRequiredPersistentEntity(OwnerEntitySpring.class), ops.getConverter()), ops);
    this.cqlSession = cqlSession;
    this.reactiveCassandraTemplate = ops;
}

public Flux<OwnerEntitySpring> searchByOwnerName(String ownerLastName) {
    return reactiveCassandraTemplate.getReactiveCqlOperations()
                                    .query(SimpleStatement
                                        .builder("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LASTNAME  + "=?")
                                        .addPositionalValues(ownerLastName)
                                        .build(), (row, rownum) -> new OwnerEntitySpring(row));
}
```

TLDR; I implemented the Spring PetClinic with Spring data Reactive and you can have access to the full code [here](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-spring-reactive) It is a step by step workshop with the code. You may want to look specially at [this folder](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-spring-reactive/tree/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/workshop/petclinic/owner/springdata)

In the project you will find reactive with the `drivers only`, reactive with `CassandraRepositories` and reactive with `SimpleCassandraRepositories`. (Check the TEST folder)